# Aligning text in SVG

Tags: xml, svg

I am trying to make SVG XML documents with a mixture of lines and brief text snippets (two or three words typically). The major problem I'm having is getting the text aligning with line segments.

For horizontal alignment I can use `text-anchor` with `left`, `middle` or `right`. I can't find a equivalent for vertical alignment; `alignment-baseline` doesn't seem to do it, so at present I'm using `dy="0.5ex"` as a kludge for centre alignment.

Is there a proper manner for aligning with the vertical centre or top of the text?

Comment: I think there is an error in your horizontal assumptions. According to http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextAnchorProperty the allowed values for `text-anchor` are `start | middle | end | inherit`. No "left" and "right" allowed.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It turns out that you don't need explicit text paths. Firefox 3 has only partial support of the vertical alignment tags ([see this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.svg/browse_thread/thread/1be0c56cfbfb3053?fwc=1)). It also seems that dominant-baseline only works when applied as a style whereas text-anchor can be part of the style or a tag attribute.

```
<path d="M10, 20 L17, 20"
      style="fill:none; color:black; stroke:black; stroke-width:1.00"/>
<text fill="black" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="16"
      x="27" y="20" style="dominant-baseline: central;">
  Vertical
</text>

<path d="M60, 40 L60, 47"
      style="fill:none; color:red; stroke:red; stroke-width:1.00"/>
<text fill="red" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="16"
      x="60" y="70" style="text-anchor: middle;">
  Horizontal
</text>

<path d="M60, 90 L60, 97"
      style="fill:none; color:blue; stroke:blue; stroke-width:1.00"/>
<text fill="blue" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="16"
      x="60" y="97" style="text-anchor: middle; dominant-baseline: hanging;">
  Bit of Both
</text>
```

This works in Firefox. Unfortunately Inkscape doesn't seem to handle dominant-baseline (or at least not in the same way).

Comment: Sadly, as of Nov 2011, Firefox is still the only browser that supports `dominant-baseline`. I still require a `<text font-size="12px"><tspan dy="6px">off set by 1/2 font size</tspan></text>`.

Comment: I'd say that at least Chrome supports it as well.

Comment: Safari seems to support it now.

Answer (score 2):

This effect can indeed be achieved by setting `alignment-baseline` to `central` or `middle`.