# How to center SVG text vertically in IE9

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-9

In order to align text vertically in SVG one has to use the `dominant-baseline` attribute.
This has already been discussed on SO ([Aligning text in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402/aligning-text-in-svg)) and is part of [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#BaselineAlignmentProperties).

My problem is with IE9 which apparently [does not support `dominant-baseline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and a bunch of [other things](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934774%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Do you have any ideas on how to approximate `dominant-baseline: central` in IE9?

Here is a sample that works in FF and Chrome. It does not work in IE9, Opera 11. Safari on Windows doesn't support `central`, but supports `middle` which is still good.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M 10 100 h 290" stroke="blue" stroke-width=".5" />
    <text x="40" y="100" font-size="16" style="dominant-baseline: auto;">
        XXX dominant-baseline: auto; XXX
    </text>

    <path d="M 10 200 h 290" stroke="blue" stroke-width=".5" />
    <text x="40" y="200" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="15" style="dominant-baseline: central;">
        XXX dominant-baseline: central XXX
    </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a giant hack, but we can approximate the vertical middle position by taking the font size into account.

The specification defines `central` like that:

> **central**
>
> This identifies a computed baseline
>   that is at the center of the EM box.

We can take an `EM box` of known font size and measure its bounding box to compute the center.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M 10 100 h 290" stroke="blue" stroke-width=".5" />
    <text id="default-text" x="20" y="100" font-size="5em">
        M
    </text>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var text = document.getElementById("default-text"),
                bbox = text.getBBox(),
                actualHeight = (100 - bbox.y),
                fontSize = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(text)["fontSize"]),
                offsetY = (actualHeight / 2) - (bbox.height - fontSize);

            text.setAttribute("transform", "translate(0, " + offsetY + ")");
        }
    </script>

    <path   d="M 10 200 h 290" stroke="blue" stroke-width=".5" />
    <text   id="reference-text" x="20" y="200" font-size="5em"
            style="dominant-baseline: central;">
        M
    </text>
</svg>
```

Obviously, the code can be much cleaner, but this is just a proof-of-concept.

Answer (score 13):

One way to accomplish this in IE is to set the position related to the size of the font:

```
<text font-size="WHATEVER YOU WANT" text-anchor="middle" "dy"="-.4em"> M </text>
```

Setting the "dy" attribute will shift the text up (if value is negative) or down (if value is positive).  Setting the "text-anchor" attribute centers the text on the x axis just fine in IE.  Although this might hackish, but so is IE's support of SVG!

Comment: Finally something that works without a page full of javascript hacks, thanks! A value of `0.3em` seems to be a better fit, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find a good way to top detect whether SVG `dominant-baseline` is supported in the current browser, so I was forced to check the `User-Agent` string (yuck). Any other suggestions?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz this is one of those "close enough" solutions that we as devs need to afford ourselves from time to time so we don't have to spend hours doing things that jeopardize sanity.  So nope...haven't thought about it since March of 2015!  For sure report back if you figure something out for anyone else that visits.

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: still checking `User-Agent` in 2019

Answer (score 4):

You could try baseline-shift to see if that works in IE9:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg width="300" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M 10 100 h 290" stroke="blue" stroke-width=".5" />
    <text x="40" y="100" font-size="16" style="dominant-baseline: auto;">
        XXX dominant-baseline: auto; XXX
    </text>

    <path d="M 10 200 h 290" stroke="blue" stroke-width=".5" />
    <text x="40" y="200" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="15" style="dominant-baseline: central;">
        XXX dominant-baseline: central XXX
    </text>

    <path d="M 10 300 h 290" stroke="blue" stroke-width=".5" />
    <text x="40" y="300" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="15">
      <tspan style="baseline-shift:-30%;">
        XXX baseline-shift: -30% XXX
      </tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Firefox doesn't seem to support baseline-shift though, but Webkit and Opera do.

Comment: It doesn't seem to support baseline-shift either. The "-30%" value does the trick in browsers that support it.