# Internet Explorer and tspan vertical alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

To vertically align a `tspan` element inside a `text` element in SVG, the CSS properties `alignment-baseline` and `dominant-baseline` work great in Chrome and in FF, respectively. So far so good.

With Internet Explorer it gets a bit crazy:

- an open [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/801719) asserts that these properties do not work for IE9-11 ...
- ... but the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh773082(v=vs.85).aspx) states that `alignment-baseline` is supported
- CSS feature-sniffing in IE9 & IE11 reports that they support `alignment-baseline` as well as `dominant-baseline` for `tspan`, *but they do not work with any values*
- to add confusion to frustration, this [MSDN dev page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) simply says both properties are currently unsupported

This wouldn't be such an issue for IE9 (one could simply [hack the desired alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510432/how-to-center-svg-text-vertically-in-ie9)), but since I want to get away from browser detection, I would like to know:

- is there a workable cross-browser solution?
- how come even IE11 doesn't support this basic SVG styling property and how to work around that?

Thanks!

Comment: Just want to remark that it's been almost 2 years since you first posted this and IE11/Edge still do not support `alignment-baseline` or `dominant-baseline`. Insane.

Comment: >2 years later: still no :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have no idea why IE doesn't support alignment-baseline, let alone why you're getting such mixed information.

You can sort of hack the same behaviour using the `dy` attribute and font-based units ("em" and "ex").  It works pretty well if you just want to center a specific text element on a point.

```
<text x="50%" y="50%" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="middle">
    This text will be centered in your coordinate system!
</text>
```

But the problem with `dy` is that -- unless `y` is also set explicitly for the same element -- it is calculated *relative to* the position of the previous character.  So if you want to center a text span relative to the surrounding spans, you have to first adjust for any previous offset and then set the new offset.  The resulting code isn't pretty:

```
<text x="50%" y="25%" font-size="150%">
    <tspan dy="0.5ex">Large font with</tspan><tspan 
        dy="-0.5ex">&nbsp;<tspan
        font-size="50%" dy="0.5ex">small font<tspan
        dy="-0.5ex">&nbsp;</tspan></tspan></tspan><tspan 
    dy="0.5ex">embedded.</tspan>
</text> 
<text x="50%" y="75%" font-size="75%">
    <tspan dy="0.5ex">Small font with</tspan><tspan 
        dy="-0.5ex">&nbsp;<tspan
        font-size="200%" dy="0.5ex">large font<tspan
        dy="-0.5ex">&nbsp;</tspan></tspan></tspan><tspan 
    dy="0.5ex">embedded.</tspan>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/awj49/

Rendering in IE11:

[image: Screen capture of fiddle example]
(gray lines mark the reference y coordinate)

If you can, it makes much cleaner code to just explicitly set the `y` attribute on each tspan:

```
<text x="50%" font-size="150%">
    <tspan y="25%" dy="0.5ex">Large font with</tspan>
    <tspan font-size="50%" y="25%" dy="0.5ex">small font</tspan>
    <tspan y="25%" dy="0.5ex">embedded.</tspan>
</text> 
<text x="50%" y="75%" font-size="75%">
    <tspan y="75%" dy="0.5ex">Small font with</tspan>
    <tspan font-size="200%" y="75%" dy="0.5ex">large font</tspan>
    <tspan y="75%" dy="0.5ex">embedded.</tspan>
</text>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/awj49/1/

The final rendering is the same:
[image: Screen capture of second fiddle example]

Comment: this is good! i was setting the `transform: translate()` property of the `text` element to 50% of its height. this is fine-ish for `text` with `tspan`s on one line, but it scales messily with multiple lines. Thanks for this :)

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't seem to support any vertical alignment CSS properties. A `tspan` is rendered with a default of what approximates `alignment-baseline: central`. Therefore, browser detection and polyfilling seems to be the only option just now to have your elements render the same across all browsers.

I adapted **AmeliaBR's** brilliant answer by manually adding to the `y` attribute of the parent `text` element to the desired difference of the font height in pixels (+50% of the font height = `hanging`, -50% = `before-edge` ...). Like so:

```
d3.selectAll('text').each( function() 
    var text = d3.select(this);
    var dy = text.attr('y') || 0;
    var h = text.style('font-size').replace('px', '') * 1;
    var nh = (dy * 1) + (h / 2);
    text.attr('y', nh);
});
```

I've used d3 here, but obviously this works with any JS library or pure JS DOM-selection.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  It's definitely not as flexible as the CSS alignment-baseline property, but so long as you have a consistent, simple structure to all your text elements you should be able to adjust.