# SVG on IE not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg

I have this SVG created on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nirmaljpatel/wtq9ocwp/

I am trying to get curved texts placed on circular arcs by specifying arced `<path>` elements for `<textpath>`s

```
<text font-size="18" font-family="Georgia" font-weight="bold" font-style="italic" fill="white">
    <textPath xlink:href="#txtHdr" font-size="20" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" fill="#484848">Types of People</textPath>
    <a href="#">
        <textPath xlink:href="#txt1" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="text-after-edge">Technical</textPath>
        <textPath xlink:href="#txt1" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="text-before-edge">Knowledge</textPath>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <textPath xlink:href="#txt2" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">Programmer</textPath>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <textPath xlink:href="#txt3" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">Debugger</textPath>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <textPath xlink:href="#txt4" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">A Tester</textPath>
    </a>
</text>
<text font-size="18"  font-family="Georgia" font-weight="bold" font-style="italic" fill="#c97">
    <tspan x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="text-after-edge">The</tspan>
    <tspan x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="text-before-edge">Master</tspan>
</text>
```

It renders correctly on Chrome.

[image: Screenshot of SVG Rendered on Chrome]

However, the same on IE displays all the `<text>` elements incorrectly.
[image: Screenshot of SVG Rendered on IE11]

Any ideas on how to get this working on IE? I am using IE11.

Adding the following 'meta' tag as suggested on some other answers did not help.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information about IE support for the `dominant-baseline` attribute is pretty mixed.

On one hand it looks like [IE supports the attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/ff972256(v=vs.85).aspx).

On the other hand, [none of the attribute values seem to be supported](http://bl.ocks.org/eweitnauer/7325338).

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513185/internet-explorer-and-tspan-vertical-alignment), my advise is to set explicitly the value of `y`.

This ensures support across all the major browsers.

Your updated code would look like this

```
<text font-size="18"  font-family="Georgia" font-weight="bold" font-style="italic" fill="#c97">
     <tspan x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle">The</tspan>
     <tspan x="0" y="20" text-anchor="middle">Master</tspan>
</text>
```

Check the [**updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wtq9ocwp/8/).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks... that definitely works for '<tspan>' elements... but doesn't seem to have any effect on the "<textpath>' elements.

Comment: @NirmalPatel Have you already tried setting explicit coordinates on the `text` element?

Comment: Finally, got it looking as it should on IE. IE does not seem to support grouped `<textpath>` elements either. Splitting each `<textpath>` under separate `<text>` element gives intended result. Here's the complete result: http://jsfiddle.net/nirmaljpatel/wtq9ocwp/.

Comment: Happy you managed to get it to work! Did you find any correct documentation about what IE does and does not support?

Comment: [2. Standards Support Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934750(v=vs.85).aspx) on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934724(v=vs.85).aspx)