# Vertical align SVG text with other SVG object to work with Inkscape

Tags: text, svg, vertical-alignment, inkscape

I am trying to align SVG text under another SVG object. This example with a SVG line works great in Firefox:

```
<svg>
    <line x1='0' y1='100' x2='100' y2='100' stroke='red'/>
    <text x='50' y='100' text-anchor='middle' font-size='24' style="dominant-baseline: text-before-edge">Text</text>
</svg>
```

The bounding-box is exactly touching the line from below which can be seen by selecting/highlighting the text.

However, unfortunately Inkscape does not support the vertical alignment with the `dominant-baseline`-style yet. (Though the horizontal alignment with the `text-anchor` seems well supported.) But I need Inkscape support. I found a `transform`-hack that seems to work in Inkscape, but I cannot figure out how to get the same effect as with the `dominant-baseline: text-before-edge`-effect. ([How to center SVG text vertically in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510432/how-to-center-svg-text-vertically-in-ie9))

#### Update

I am using the browser with JavaScript to generate the svg. So it would be okay (re)calculate the position of the SVG text element in the browser to make it usable for Inkscape. However, even with this extension made explicit (being implicit from the suggested `transform`-hack above) I am still lacking a solution.

Answer (score 2):

How about trying with `dy`?:

```
<svg>
    <line x1='0' y1='100' x2='100' y2='100' stroke='red'/>
    <text x='50' y='100' text-anchor='middle' font-size='24' dy="1em">Text</text>
</svg>
```

You can adjust the position of the text below the line, by adjusting the em value.  And the same em value should work for all font sizes - as long as the font is the same.

Haven't checked that it works with Inkscape though...

**Update**

Ok. It looks like Inkscape doesn't like it if we specify a `dy` on the `<text>` element.  But it is okay if the `dy` is on a `<tspan>`.  Also, it won't accept ems as a unit.  It wants pixels.  So if we update my sample accordingly:

```
<svg>
    <line x1='0' y1='100' x2='100' y2='100' stroke='red'/>
    <text x='50' y='100' text-anchor='middle' font-size='24'>
        <tspan dy="19">Text</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Inkscape will load it fine.  The only thing is that you will have to tweak the `dy` value for each font and font-size you use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, there is no `dy` support in Inkscape. So this does not work. (Also setting `dy` to `1em` does not even give the same result as `style="dominant-baseline: text-before-edge"` in Firefox. This becomes even more apparent at higher fontsizes, e.g. `100`. The bounding box does not touch the line anymore.)

Comment: I experimented and found a solution that works - if you can accept the limitations.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The bounding box was a bit too high this time for my configuration (Firefox on Windows). It seems to work with a `dy` of 90% of the fontsize. However, the right `dy` will be highly dependent on the font used. So this is a too severely limited solution for me, since I need to use different fonts (even custom fonts that I cannot check beforehand). It seems strange how hard it is to get such an on the face of it easy task done. Somehow it should be possible to calculate where the baseline of a given font sits in the bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

I just worked around a problem like yours and wanted to share my approach.

I'm rendering a text and I was already using  `inkscape --query-all tempfile.svg` to get metrics about the line lengths I wanted to typeset.

I ended up trying to figure the baseline by **actually rendering a capital "M" on the chosen font** (*Droid Sans*, right now) then using the queried height to figure out the baseline offset:

```
$baseline=$fontSize*$previousBaseline/$previousFontSize;
```

It's... *extremely rough*, but it works nicely with inkscape.