# text-align="middle" _only_ in y-direction?

Tags: text, svg, alignment, text-alignment

I can use `text-align="middle"` on a text element to center text. Actually this only works nice for the x-direction. For the y-direction I use the hack of Ian G in question [Aligning text in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402/aligning-text-in-svg).

But what can I do, if a want to center a text in the y-direction, but want to left-align the text in x-direction? 
For example, I have a `rect`-element and a `text`-element positioned right of it. The text should be vertically aligned to appear centered in relation to the rect. Therefore I use the `text-align="middle"` property. But I want to left-align the text in the x-direction (since I want to display it at the right of the rect). That doesn't work, since `text-align` always applies the both, `x` and `y` values.

Actually I am not really happy with the vertical alignment in that way and would prefer something else. But didn't find a better solution yet. (I can't use the `dominant-baseline` attribute, since I am using Batik, which doesn't support it.) I can't even calculate it myself, since in SVG I have no way to query the ascent/descent/baseline of a font.

Answer (score 2):

The `baseline`-related attributes, as you have discovered, are not universally supported (yet).

One possible solution is to use a method similar to the old CSS trick for vertical centering.

Set the y coord of the text to the vertical centre of the object you want to center on.  Then use dy with an em value to adjust the text verically.

```
<text x="0" y="100" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20pt" dy="0.35em">Some TEXT</text>
```

The amount of `dy` won't be 0.5em as you might think because the visual centre of the font won't be exactly half the em height.  It will vary from font to font.  But once you find a good `dy` value for a particular font, it should work for any font-size.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/js88W/1/

Try changing the font-size value to confirm it stays centred.