# Vertically align text inside of the svg circle

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to centre the `<text>` inside of the `<path>` element. Path is a circle drawn using [@opsb](https://jsfiddle.net/cqr3zfLk/) great answer. I can centre the text horizontally using `text-anchor='middle'`.

Is there a way to centre it Vertically?

```
<svg width="200px" height="200px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id='path' fill="transparent" stroke='red' stroke-width='6'/>
  <text x="100" y="100" font-family="Verdana" font-size="50" fill="blue" text-anchor='middle'>5</text>
</svg>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqr3zfLk/) with the javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vertical alignment of text element in SVG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250403/vertical-alignment-of-text-element-in-svg)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253766/text-align-middle-only-in-y-direction/19273331

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Svg center text

Since svg is responsive
I usually put in a hard value that is about the radius of the circle.

So simply by adding: 
`transform="translate(0, 15)`

```js
function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
  var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees - 90) * Math.PI / 180.0;

  return {
    x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
    y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
  };
}

function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {

  var start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
  var end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);

  var arcSweep = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";

  var d = [
    "M", start.x, start.y,
    "A", radius, radius, 0, arcSweep, 0, end.x, end.y
  ].join(" ");

  return d;
}

$('#path').attr("d", describeArc(100, 100, 50, 0, 180));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="200px" height="200px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id='path' fill="transparent" stroke='red' stroke-width='6' />
  <text x="100" y="100" transform="translate(0, 15)" font-family="Verdana" font-size="50" fill="blue" text-anchor='middle'>5</text>
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" fill="black" r="2" />
  <circle cx="100" cy="50" fill="black" r="2" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use alignment-baseline to centre text vertically.

Something like this:

```html
<text x="100" y="100" font-family="Verdana" font-size="50" fill="blue" text-anchor='middle' alignment-baseline="central">5</text>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can now use `dominant-baseline="central"` to vertically align the text without javascript.

```html
<svg width="150px" height="150px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="69" stroke="red" fill="none" stroke-width="6" />
  <text x="75" y="75" font-family="Verdana" font-size="50" fill="blue" text-anchor='middle' dominant-baseline="central">5</text>
</svg>
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline)

Comment: What a pleasant surprise. This solved my issue.